# Reading query strings from GET inside Spring web flow

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

Hy.

Im continuing a spring web flow, using execution key. (an order paypal payment)
and would need to read query strings from get. &TokenID and &PayerID

this is how the URL looks like where Paypal redirects user after confirming payment:

```
/sampleflow?execution=e1s1&_eventId=approved&token=EC5D7416956W8431713&PayerID=TN2RE8ZTH67JN
```

if eventID is approved, my flow redirects to a payment confirmed state. This part is working.
I just need to get the query string parameters somehow.

Any way to do this?

Comment: I don't understand where the difficulty is. `request.getParameter("token")` will return `"EC5D7416956W8431713"`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm assuming you are trying to access the request parameters in the flow definition xml file. You can access the params using the EL variable **requestParameters**.

```
<evaluate expression="someService.doSomething(requestParameters.TokenID, requestParameters.PayerID)" />
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/2.3.x/reference/html/el.html#el-variable-requestParameters

Answer (score 0):

The link above didn't work for me, but I was able to find the relevant page at this address:
[4.4.6. requestParameters](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/2.3.x/reference/html/el.html#el-variable-requestParameters)

Comment: I would have commented above, but my fu is still too weak.